# '+=' operator overloading type not viable

Tags: c++

I take

```
./Mission.h:56:11: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Passenger *' to
      'const Passenger' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
        Mission& operator+=(const Passenger &passenger);
                 ^
./Mission.h:58:11: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Passenger *' to
      'const Astronaut' for 1st argument
        Mission& operator+=(const Astronaut &astronaut);
```

And I define in header file the overloaded func

```
Mission& operator+=(const Astronaut &astronaut);
```

In func define

```
Mission& Mission::operator+=(const Astronaut &astronaut){
```

implementing

```
moonMission += astronautList[0];
    moonMission += astronautList[1];
    moonMission += astronautList[2];
```

I define array like this

```
Astronaut* astronautList[5];
```

Why it is not viable? I want to send my pointer array to a overloaded function and array define can't be changed. I only allowed to change overloaded function.

Comment: `moonMission += astronautList[0];` -- `atronautList[0]` is a pointer. Now does your `+=` take pointers, or a reference?

Comment: Also, why an array of 5 pointers, instead of `Astronaut astronautList[5];`?  If you had that, your code would or should have worked.  So it's either you have the wrong declaration, or the right declaration using the pointers, but with a missing dereference.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it takes reference. Should it be 'Mission& Mission::operator+=(const Astronaut *astronaut){
 '

Comment: Now you are changing the signature instead of fixing how you call `+=`.  I suggest you fix how you're calling the function instead of changing the function signature.

Comment: You need to decide if it is appropriate to add pointers rather than actual objects.   Accepting a reference means you can add objects.   Accepting a pointer means something else (typically, taking ownership of an object created elsewhere which means then your class is responsible for destroying the passed object).   I suppose a Mission of destroying astronauts might be relevant in some situations, but wouldn't bet it is a good idea for your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sir, I can't change it. It is given to me and I am expected to write proper overloaded function.

Comment: @KaanUslu -- Please state clearly what can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator +=` takes a reference, not a pointer.

Since you have this:

```
Astronaut* astronautList[5];
```

you need to dereference the pointer:

```
moonMission += *(astronautList[0]);
```

The other lines of code would have similar changes.